# When does CloudKit purge a CKRecordZone?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am having trouble finding information about when CloudKit “purges” a record zone. I even did a search at Apple‘s developer documentation section of their website. “Purge” really is the word Apple uses. My question arose when I was reading Apple’s documentation on [CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckfetchdatabasechangesoperation).

I am using swift. I just didn’t want to put the swift tag so that only Swift users sees my gf post.